# Multiple sliders (bxSlider) with page counter

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I have a page which contains multiple content sliders (using jQuery bxSlider) and a single page counter. Each slider is contained within a collapsing div, the opening and closing of which is controlled using 3 buttons.

This can be shown working here - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dan_t/ZHDQ6/)

When a new slider is opened, the total number of slides for that slider is not being displayed correctly. Using the (commented out) alert, I can see that the show.getSlideCount is returned for each of the three sliders in sequence and so always ends up as 3 (being the number of slides in the last of the three sliders). When you click the next arrow to view the second slide, the total number of pages is then shown correctly for each slider.

I'm sure it's something very obvious but I can't seem to work out why the slidecount works correctly for the next and previous slide functions, but not for the slider load. Here is the script I'm using for bxSlider

```
$('.bxslider').each(function(){
    var show = $(this);

    show.bxSlider({
    pager: false,
    infiniteLoop: false,
    hideControlOnEnd: true,
    slideMargin: 350,
    onSliderLoad: function (){
        show.goToSlide(0);
        var slide_count = show.getSlideCount();
        var slide_curr = show.getCurrentSlide();
        // alert (slide_count);
        insertCount(slide_curr,slide_count);
    },
    onSlideNext: function (){
        var slide_count = show.getSlideCount();
        var slide_curr = show.getCurrentSlide();
        insertCount(slide_curr,slide_count);
    },
    onSlidePrev: function (){
        var slide_count = show.getSlideCount();
        var slide_curr = show.getCurrentSlide();
        insertCount(slide_curr,slide_count);
    }                               
    });             
});
```

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

instead of building your own n/x counter for bxslider, you could use the built-in counter:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
    pager: true,
    pagerType: 'short'
});
```